# Open new Numbers document in older Numbers

Tags: macos, numbers

I have a Numbers (v3.5) file from a Yosemite install. I have since abandoned Yosemite (here is why [WindowServer high CPU on Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153397/windowserver-high-cpu-on-yosemite/163057#163057)).

Now I cannot open this file in Mavericks' Numbers (v2.3) app. I do not want to upgrade my whole OS X to open a single file.

Is there a way around this other than upgrading to Yosemite or finding a machine with Yosemite on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hack, but assuming that your document won't be damaged by undergoing some slight changes, here is what I would do.

1. Logon to [www.iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/), and open Numbers. If it isn't there, go to [beta.iCloud.com](https://beta.icloud.com/).
2. Upload the new Numbers document to iCloud and then open the document in your browser.
3. Select Download a Copy from the settings menu (as seen in the screenshot below) and choose to save it as a Word document.
4. Open the Word document in Numbers and save/export in whatever format you wish.

[image: Download a Copy]

### Alternate Approach:

You could, depending on the nature of the document, send it to a friend who has Yosemite and ask them to export it to the Numbers '09 format.

*Other Options:*

- If I were you, and did want to mess with importing/export I'd probably try [CloudConvert.com](https://cloudconvert.com/).
- [This article claims](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5994) you may be able to revert the document, although the fact that you can't open it in the first place would seem to negate that option.

Comment: But its Numbers, not Pages?

Comment: It appears this works for Numbers too. The export to Excel works but messes up my layout and tables. Which is fine, but for now its sufficient to use the document via the iCloud interface.

Comment: Oops - sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to your question. I'll edit for Numbers. That's what I was concerned about and hence the first sentence because exporting like that (especially with Numbers) is bound to mess at least some formatting up.