# Slow Computer Question

Tags: imac, memory

I use a Mid-2011 iMac 21.5" (with 4 users on it).

I have noticed that the computer is runs quite slow when I am the only one logged in. The only applications I typically have open at once are Xcode, Safari and occasionally some other applications such as Reminders and notes.

When I checked Activity monitor to see how much RAM it was using, I noticed it said it had used 3.97-3.99 out of the 4 GB of ram that it has (See Screenshot).

[image: Memory Usage Screenshot]

here is the cpu graph:

[image: CPU Load Screenshot]

I also ran EtreCheck as requested, however I was not expierencing the slowness as much when I ran it:

https://gist.github.com/Computer-Whiz123/e86e014e239b87b367df

I will upload one when I experience slowness...

I am considering buying extra RAM but I wanted to make sure that this was actually the cause of the problem before investing in $100 RAM chips.

Would upgrading the RAM from 4 GB to maybe 8 or 16 GB fix the issue? If not, what would fix the issue? Is there anything else that needs fixing?

Comment: For me, a cure for "slow Yosemite syndrome" was to fix the user, group, and permissions on "/usr/local".  For details, see my answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/152044/113575

Comment: it's not just Yosemite; I was noticing slowness when I had mavericks. But after I installed Yosemite, I noticed that the computer got a little faster...

Comment: We really need more information about your system to answer the question. Please download and run [EtreCheck](http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck), past the results into a [gist](https://gist.github.com) and update your question with a link.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan done

Comment: @Developer_ACE Thanks for posting that. I'd look into getting rid of any of those plugins and extensions that you don't recognise, particularly the one that EtreCheck identifies as Adware. But, to my eyes, nothing particularly stands out from a performance standpoint in that EtreCheck scan. Although you can see that there was obviously a problem at some point in the last two days since various things were "killed due to memory pressure".

Comment: i ran a scan just now and it seems like there were less things killed... I also removed that plugin...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your Memory, but if you wish to upgrade do so.

The slow computer has other reason, so we need to see your full activity monitor to help you.

Here is a sample of my memory (at about same levels as yours) without slow computer part.

[image: ram usage]

Comment: why is your memory pressure graph green compared to mine?

Comment: yours is doing more work, you have already 1.2 Gig compressed while I have only 200 meg. Again, adding Memory will help but that is not the main reason for slowness.

Comment: What exactly is the compressed memory? What contribtes to it? How do I make it go down? Additionally, if I get, say 4 more GB of RAM, how much do you think it will help?

Comment: As your Mac approaches maximum memory capacity, OS X automatically compresses data from "inactive apps", making more memory available. Thus it is a indication you could use more memory, but still would like to help you with slow computer if you show me the CPU usage. As for how much more RAM, if you get 4 more it will last you for a while (a Year or 2) then you need more and so on :)

Comment: added CPU to original question...

Comment: Great, or not, the CPU shows no reason for slowness ? Try starting in safe mode to check the computer speed without some 3d party applications running.

Comment: How do I do that? Also, FYI the CPU graph was takes a few mins after the computer was asleep...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21100/discussion-between-developer-ace-and-buscar).